# Multi-Document Transactions not Working using MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

**UPDATE**

After some suggestions I modifies the code like this:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession()
session.startTransaction()
try {
    const udpated = await Schema1.findByIdAndUpdate(
        'id', { $set: { /* ... */ } }, { session }
    )
    const array = await Promise.all(
        updated.array.map(async item => {
            // change 1
            const doc = await Schema2.findById(item.someId).session(session)
            const payload = { /* ... */ }
            // change 2
            return new Schema3(payload).save({ session })
        })
    )
    await session.commitTransaction()
    session.endSession()
} catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction()
    session.endSession()
    throw err
}
```

But that gives me another error:

```
{
    MongoError: internal atlas error checking things: Failure getting dbStats: read tcp 192.168.254.116:52242->192.168.254.116:27000: i/o timeout
    at /some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63
    at authenticateStragglers (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'internal atlas error checking things: Failure getting dbStats: read tcp 192.168.254.116:52242->192.168.254.116:27000: i/o timeout',
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
× Unexpected error occured MongoError: internal atlas error checking things: Failure getting dbStats: read tcp 192.168.254.116:52242->192.168.254.116:27000: i/o timeout
    at /some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63
    at authenticateStragglers (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/some-path/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

Btw.: I also refactored that code without using `mongoose` (I just used the standard `mongodb` client for `nodejs` and I am still getting those errors.

---

I am using `mongoose` transactions because of my problem referred to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002664/node-js-mongoose-undo-database-modifications-on-error.).

However, my problem is, that my implementation of `Promise.all()` doesn't seem to work with `mongoose` transactions. The issue probably comes from using multiple `Schemas` with one `session` or creating an array of documents. (But I am really not sure)

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession()
session.startTransaction()
try {
    const udpated = await Schema1.findByIdAndUpdate(
        'id', { $set: { /* ... */ } }, { session }
    )
    const array = await Promise.all(
        updated.array.map(async item => {
            const doc = await Schema2.findById(item.someId)
            const payload = { /* ... */ }
            return Schema3.createa(payload, { session })
        })
    )
    await session.commitTransaction()
    session.endSession()
} catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction()
    session.endSession()
    throw err
}
```

I am getting errors, that the validation of `Schema3` failed for some required paths. Even though `payload` is found when console.log it.

```
{ ValidationError: xxx validation failed: xxx: Path `xxx` is required., xxx: Path `xxx` is required., xxx: Path `xxx` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (util.js:400:38)
    at inspect (util.js:294:10)
    at format (util.js:223:18)
    at Console.log (console.js:130:21)
    at module.exports (xxx.js:228:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  errors:
   { xxx:
      { ValidatorError: Path `xxx` is required.
    at new ValidatorError (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
    at validate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:871:13)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:924:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:880:19)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1913:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
        message: 'Path `xxx` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'xxx',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true },
     xxx:
      { ValidatorError: Path `xxx` is required.
    at new ValidatorError (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
    at validate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:871:13)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:924:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:880:19)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1913:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
        message: 'Path `xxx` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'xxx',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true },
     xxx:
      { ValidatorError: Path `xxx` is required.
    at new ValidatorError (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
    at validate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:871:13)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:924:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:880:19)
    at /xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1913:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
        message: 'Path `xxx` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'xxx',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'xxx validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

---

When refactoring the code without using `mongoose` transactions, everything works just fine:

```
try {
    const udpated = await Schema1.findByIdAndUpdate(
        'id', { $set: { /* ... */ } }
    )
    const array = await Promise.all(
        updated.array.map(async item => {
            const doc = await Schema2.findById(item.someId)
            const payload = { /* ... */ }
            return Schema3.createa(payload)
        })
    )
} catch (err) {
    throw err
}
```

Comment: I believe that if you use Promise.all you don't need async/await inside the map function. Try to remove it.

Comment: Did not work :-(

Comment: is createa an async function? or only find by id?

Comment: `create`  returns a `Promise`

Comment: Maybe try and split into 2 different loops, i.e.: `updated.array = Promise.all(updated.array.map(item => Schema2.findById(item.someId)))` and same for the remaining part of the code.

Comment: I've updated my question... the `Promise.all()` is not the issue. The problem is caused by the `mongoose` transactions

Comment: @Florian Make sure you have installed mongodb 4.0 which supports transactions.

Comment: I have version 4. I contacted the support and it's a known problem that will be fixed with version 4.0.5. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted the MongoDB Support and it turned out that this is a known issue:

> We are currently aware of an issue with the M0 Free Tier clusters whereby multi-statement transactions timeout with an error. This should be fixed with the rollout of MongoDB version 4.0.5. In the meantime, if you require this feature urgently, I would recommend that you upgrade your cluster to an M10+ cluster.

So the issue occurs because I am using the free tier. But the bug will hopefully be fixed with the MongoDB 4.0.5 release.

**UPDATE**

As my database runs now on version 4.0.5, the problem is fixed. So it wasn't necessarily a issue with the code.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding  `.session(session)` to each Query

```
const doc = await Schema2.findById(item.someId).session(session)
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-session

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, after changing I get a new error (I updated my question)

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you for create/save transactions. Solutions in this discussion don't seem to do the trick either https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6761

Comment: I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254164 and it seems this bug can't be fixed

Comment: I contacted the mongodb support. Maybe they will do something about it

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice yet. The problem is fixed by upgrading to 4.0.5 (it's available now)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a session option in `findOne()`:

```
const doc = await Schema2.findById(item.someId, null, { session })
```

See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i created a document in a session, then i used the ._id, created from other document "B", and then find the first document with other property, when the first document, i pushed that B in the first document, the solutions that i try was using multiples `session.startTransaction();`

example:

```
session.startTransaction();
```

create first document

```
 await session.commitTransaction();
 session.startTransaction();
```

create second document, search the first document with other property 
with which it was created, and push this B._id into the first document and then updated this first document

```
await session.commitTransaction();
```

and for the end `session.endSession()`

I realized this when i did a console.log(first document) when i search it again and push b into them, just i think, its like a commit in the cluster? so maybe with other session works... and it worked